# Curve Fitting in Matlab

Tags: math, matlab, curve

Given two points say (1,2,3) and (4,7,8). The endpoint tangents at these points are also given as inputs say pi/4 and -pi/2 respectively. How to fit a helix of arc length 2 between these points?
How to implement this in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what toolboxes you have access to, but you should check the documentation for these two:

- [Curve Fitting toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/curvefit/curvefit.shtml)
- [Spline toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/splines/splines.shtml)

I think there may be a number of different ways you could approach the problem (i.e. different types of curves to use to match an arbitrary set of points and tangents).